# Minimum of two constraints

Tags: cplex, ilog

I want to write a minimum function in OPL.

```
forall(p in P) sum(n in N)Q6[n][p]==(Max_Rema[p]*Dem[p])

forall(n in N)sum(p in P)Q6[n][p]<=sum(m in M)Q4[m][n];
```

I want that `Q6` should be equal to minimum of`Max_Rema[p]*Dem[p]` and `sum(m in M)Q4[m][n]`, where `Max_Rema` and `Dem[p]` are parameters.

How to write this?

Answer (score 0):

minl will do that

```
int minofs1=minl(1, 2 ,5 ,10, 7 ,8);
float minofs2=minl(2.5 ,1.522e2, -10.2);

dvar int x;
dvar int y;
dvar int z;

subject to
{
  x==4;
  y==7;
  z==minl(x,y);
}



execute
{
   writeln("minl(1, 2 ,5 ,10, 7 ,8) gives ",minofs1);
   writeln("minll(2.5 ,1.522e2, -10.2) gives ",minofs2);
   writeln(z);
}
```

gives

```
minl(1, 2 ,5 ,10, 7 ,8) gives 1
minll(2.5 ,1.522e2, -10.2) gives -10.2
4
```